# How can I switch between two forms opened on C# in Visual Studio without opening a new page each time?

Tags: c#

f1 form opened 1st page. f2 form opened page 2 and took it to f1. How can I switch to the same f1 form? (I don't want it to open a new page)

This is a game. menu popup game screen appears. When the game is over, clicking the start menu opens a new game page. I want it to open on the first opened game page

Comment: The f2 form instance needs a reference to the correct f1 form instance.

Comment: Dont close the forms, just hide and show them.